# How to make Action<param,param2> compatible with event's delegate type?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, compatibility, action

Given the code below:

```
void LookupBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action d = delegate
        {
            if (!_p.AutoClose)
                CloseLookupBox();
        };

    if (this.ParentForm.MdiParent != null)
        this.ParentForm.MdiParent.Deactivate += delegate { d(); };
    else
        this.ParentForm.Deactivate += delegate { d(); };
}
```

Is there a way to omit the delegate { d(); } ?

```
void LookupBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action<object,EventArgs> d = delegate
        {
            if (!_p.AutoClose)
                CloseLookupBox();
        };

    if (this.ParentForm.MdiParent != null)
        this.ParentForm.MdiParent.Deactivate += d;
    else
        this.ParentForm.Deactivate += d;
}
```

Note: I want to do this inline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely - change the type of `d` to start with:

```
EventHandler d = delegate
    {
        if (!_p.AutoClose)
            CloseLookupBox();
    };
```

Anonymous methods don't just work with Func and Action...

For future reference though, you *can* create a new delegate based on an existing one with a compatible signature:

```
Action<object, EventArgs> d = ...;
EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(d);
```

But this extra indirection is pointless in this case :)

You can also make the code calling it slightly simpler too using the null-coalescing operator:

```
Form form = ParentForm.MdiParent ?? ParentForm;
form.Deactivate += d;
```

As you're then only using `d` once, you could inline it, turning the whole method into:

```
Form form = ParentForm.MdiParent ?? ParentForm;
form.Deactivate += delegate
{
    if (!_p.AutoClose)
        CloseLookupBox();
};
```

Comment: Whoops, you're right; he's using a vanilla EventHandler, so I guess the generic isn't required.  Does using the generic incur any penalty performancewise?

Comment: Well you've got to subscribe with the right type, so you'd have to create a nongeneric instance anyway...

Comment: +1 for null coalesce operator suggestion. your mind can really pick up every program's intent.

Answer (score 2):

Not much better, but you could do if you're using C# 3.0:

```
if (this.ParentForm.MdiParent != null)
    this.ParentForm.MdiParent.Deactivate += (x,y) => d();
else
    this.ParentForm.Deactivate += (x,y) => d();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [EventHandler<MyEventArgs>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) to define those instead of the Action delegate

```
  EventHandler<EventArgs> d = delegate        
       {            
            if (!_p.AutoClose)                
               CloseLookupBox();        
       };
```